# Optional Catch Binding throwing error on node:21-alpine docker image

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, npm

I get the following error:

```
> node app.js
auth  | 
auth  | /api/node_modules/busboy/lib/utils.js:469
auth  |     } catch {}
auth  |             ^
auth  | 
auth  | SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

when running my docker image on my server. I was using `node:9-slim` before and realised that was ridiciously old and hoped using a more up-to-date and relavent image `(node:21-alpine)` for this old project would fix this issue as it adds support for Optional Catch Bindings. But I still get the error and I'm unsure why.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:21-alpine
WORKDIR /api
COPY package.json /api
RUN npm install
COPY . /api
CMD ["npm", "start"]
EXPOSE 5010
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "auth",
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "<>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/joi": "^17.1.1",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^8.1.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.4.3",
    "express-rate-limit": "^7.1.5",
    "firebase": "^10.7.1",
    "geoip-lite": "^1.4.9",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.7.0",
    "request-ip": "^3.3.0",
    "speakeasy": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "marked": "^11.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's been supported [since v10](https://node.green/#ES2019-misc-optional-catch-binding) so v21 certainly shouldn't be a problem (I'd suggest v20 though as it's LTS). Are you sure you've rebuilt the image?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've gone back to a very old project hence the massive jump from v9 to v21. I will try v20. I have rebuilt the image yes. GitHub action builds my images for me before sending it off to my registry. I have pulled the image down on my Mac to see if my server was pulling the latest image down and it is.

Comment: A [mre] using unbound `catch {}` in `node:21-alpine` works fine for me.